# Pandas: Read a text file that contains separators in the content of the fields

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the Pandas "read_CSV" function to take the content of a TXT file (to later save it as a CSV).

The file in question has separator | (pipe), but the problem is that it also, in certain fields, contains that same symbol. For example:

```
|Field1|Field2|Field3|
|Content1|Content2|Cont|ent3|
```

So when I try to read the file using **SEP="|"**, I get "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected N fields in line XX , saw N+1", basically because there is a pipe between the data and one more field is generated.

I have the same problem with other files that are separated by **";"**

Is there a way to deal with these exceptions? In addition to making a "skip" to that type of row, since it is not desired.

Thanks

EDIT:

As Tim mentions in his answer, the first example requires having quotes. I will exemplify with another case:

```
"Field1";"Field2"
"Value1";"("value2";"Value3")" -> this is supposed to be all together in field 2
```

As you can see, the field contains additional quotes and also includes a separator in between.

Can those kinds of cases be solved?

Comment: No, there is no way.  You need to fix the data.  Not even a human could do this.  How could pandas possibly know whether it was intended to be a field separator not?  This is why you are supposed to use quoting for fields with special characters.

Comment: Okay, let me edit the question to focus on the fields in quotes.

Comment: Added example is still invalid data. Since you're using double quotes to mark the boundaries of a field, you need to escape the double quotes within the field. So it should be `"Value1";"(\"value2\";\"Value3\")"`.

You misunderstood the comment. They said "quoting for fields with special characters". So you should have changed `|Content1|Content2|Cont|ent3|` to `|Content1|Content2|"Cont|ent3"|`. Now, again, if you are to use double quotes within a field, you need to escape them with backslashes